# How to turn a list of object properties in a single string into actual objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I would want to turn the below string into actual objects. It seems JSON.parse does not work in the below scenario as all the properties are bundled in a single string instead of separately. The text string come from api request.

Convert

```
var s ="{prop1:\"value\", prop2:\"value2\", prop3:\"value3\"}";
```

into

```
s = {prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'};
```

Comment: The problem with this JSON string is that the keys are not surrounded by `"`, e.g., it should be `"prop1" : "value"`. So, unless the string is formatted to the standard, `JSON.parse` will not work

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: maybe combining some `s.split(":")` with some additional regex would be my suggestion, but I guess there could be smarter answers :)

Comment: my suggestion, would be complicated to implement, and perhaps be very buggy :(

Comment: `It seems JSON.parse does not work in the below scenario`. Back up a little bit, where is this string coming from? Are you perhaps requesting it from an API and reading it as text instead of accepting it as JSON?

Comment: Thanks, it is coming from api

Comment: @davidlee - show the code where you make the request to the API. Do you use XHR? `fetch`? Another library? You need to get the response as JSON.

Comment: @davidlee - ignore the answers below, while they may work, they are not the actual answers you want, you need to fix this problem at the source.

Comment: @Adam I agree with you.

Comment: @Adam Apparently it's an API that returns javascript or something similar (YAML?) instead of JSON

Comment: @slebetman - it could be a problem on the API side - they might be trying to encode JSON by hand and if the OP has control over the API, then that's the problem that should be fixed instead of any client side stuff at all.

Comment: Bottom line, whatever regex-y solution the OP is presented with will most likely end up working only some of the time, but not all of it. And then the OP will be back looking for a solution to his regexp problem....[you know what they say about regexp solutions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @Adam Obviously. But 99% of the time when you need to do this it's because you don't own the API. Way back when, before Crockford formalized JSON, people have been doing this as an alternative to XML. I've even seen some APIs sending `function () {...}` over which can't be done with JSON. Sometimes you may need to interface with these legacy systems

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s ="{prop1:\"value\", prop2:\"value2\", prop3:\"value3\"}"

console.log(x(s))

function x (string){
  let resObj = {}
  string.replaceAll(' ','').replaceAll('"','').replaceAll('{','').replaceAll('}','').split(',').map(x=>{
    const tmp = x.split(':')
    resObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
  })
  return resObj
}
```

Or simply:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(s.replaceAll("{",'{"').replaceAll(', ',', "').replaceAll(':','":')))
```

Comment: This solution will not work for all the values, think if json property value has comma in it or for that matter ':' in it

Answer (score -1):

How about use `eval()`

```
eval('var s =' + "{prop1:\"value\", prop2:\"value2\", prop3:\"value3\"}");
```

I know eval is not best solution.

however if you don't want to split string, it's one of solution...

Comment: Yup. This is the old-school solution. You can run some regexp pre-checks to disable code injection if necessary but back in the web2.0 days we wouldn't even do that if the data comes from trusted sources

Comment: Good advice. the text data is not actually 'JSON'. I just give a way to solve his problem.

Comment: I have given this a try and got the error msg instead: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: function a(_callback) {
    eval('var s =' + "{prop1:\"value\", prop2:\"value2\", prop3:\"value3\"}");
    _callback(s)
}

a(function(_val){
    console.log(_val.prop1)
})